# Can't Upload multiple azure blobs contents ( text and Image) to Azure SQL table

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

At the moment i can only upload one blobtype( text) with the below trigger

```
#r "System.Configuration"
#r "System.Data"
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;

public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
    string detail = ($"{name}");


    var str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqldb_connection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        conn.Open();
  var text = "INSERT INTO PhotoTable(CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,IsDeleted, Url, Title) " +
           "VALUES (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), 'true', 'yrhrh', @Name)";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
            // Execute the command and log the # rows affected.
            var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            log.Info($"{rows} rows were updated");
        }
    }
}
```

Have 2 questions 
01)Is their any way that i can upload two types at the same time to azure SQLstorage ??( such as text blob and image blob)

02) with this trigger i am only getting the ID of the blob storage not the contents ,that also an issue is their any way that i can get the contents of the blob-storage as well?? ,

help will be highly appreciated , thank you

Comment: Was the provided answer helpful to your scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** It is possible to upload different kinds of files into Azure SQL using SSIS, The following video [**tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRnniMM0Uuk) shows you a step by step guide on how to do it

**2)** number two, you can use **OPENROWSET**,  parses a file stored in Blob storage and returns the content of the file as a set of rows
The following example shows a BULK INSERT command that loads the content of the file into SQL Database:

```
BULK INSERT Product
FROM 'data/product.dat'
WITH ( DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorageAccount');
```

More info can be found [**here**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/preview-loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-sql-database/)